# how can I know MAC ADRESSES connected to a given AP [windows]?

Tags: windows, wifi, wireshark, mac-address, mac-spoofing

I think that the question is clear.
I want to know the mac adresses of people connected to a certain wireless network.                       Thank you!

Comment: Is this a network that you administer?

Comment: MAC of AP or of clients on AP?

Comment: If it's of the clients you can just do an ARP scan.

Comment: Are you an administrator looking to see what devices are connected to your network, or are you a malicious client trying to pretend to be another client?

Answer (score 3):

Neither method requires WEP nor WPA authorized access to the network, just proximity.

In Windows I use Nirsoft WiFi Channel Monitor to expose the MAC's on a particular AP. It's a single file/no installation truly portable app.
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_channel_monitor.html
[image]
It requires MS Netmon drivers but they're free and ready to use without a reboot:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/netmon/p/downloads/

Kismet inside most LIVE Linux Distributions and always inside Kali gives an even broader view. From its pull down menus, select Clients view or just split the screen and scroll through the listed AP's to display connected systems and their MAC's.
https://tools.kali.org/wireless-attacks/kismet

[image]

Comment: I was thinking that the admin portal to a network that the asker administered would provide that info without installing software.  But this is a better answer.

Comment: @baldPrussian, an admin portal would be better because you would be certain to get all the clients connected to a  wireless network. With this method, you only get the clients located in a limited proximity around the listening station. Even with a single access point, if the station running this software is further from another client than it is from the AP (for instance opposite sides), then it won't find the client. If the network has multiple APs (on multiple channels), then your chances of getting all clients diminishes significantly.